# how to mark points(using latitude and longitude) from pandas data frame using plotly python with satellite view

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, openstreetmap, plotly-python

i want to mark points(using latitude and longitude) from pandas data frame using plotly python with satellite view.
sample df:

```
    device  GPSTime     GPSLat       GPSLng
    101    1614956574   16.94469    29.8267
    102    1615271467   16.94503    29.83
    103    1615271488   16.94553    29.83
```

i plot the data using Plotly but didn't get the satellite view. Is there any way to get a satellite view for this?

mycode:

```
import plotly.express as px 
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(dfL, lat="GPSLat", lon="GPSLng", zoom=15, height=500,width=1000,color="device")
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map") 
fig.show()
```

current view :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY57G.jpg)

But I need to plot these data on satalite image? Is there any way to get a satellite view for this?

Comment: import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='Add Your Key here')

# Geocoding an address
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')
# Look up an address with reverse geocoding
reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((40.714224, -73.961452))
directions_result = gmaps.directions("Sydney Town Hall",
                                     "Parramatta, NSW",
                                     mode="transit",
                                     departure_time=now)
I think it may help to you.i cannot get your actual point

Comment: import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='Add Your Key here')

# Geocoding an address
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')
# Look up an address with reverse geocoding
reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((40.714224, -73.961452))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to use mapbox, you need to get the APIKey of [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/). Once you have the APIKey, you can use the following code to draw the satellite image with the style specified.

```
import plotly.express as px

px.set_mapbox_access_token(open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read())
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df,
                        lat=df.GPSLat,
                        lon=df.GPSLng,
                        hover_name="device",
                        height=500, width=1000,
                        zoom=15, mapbox_style='satellite')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please check this.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66597333/how-to-get-the-radius-of-the-biggest-bubble-python-plotly-open-street-map